# Java Timer Speeds Up Every Execution

Tags: java, timer

Every time my timer is run, the code executed inside the timer is run faster.  Why is this happening?

This code essentially moves a label (holding an image) across the frame.
Every run, the images moves faster.

[image]

```
if (Player.direction == "west") {
            timerWest.start();
            isCasting = true;
            new Magic("westmagic.gif");

            timerWest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int x = Frame.fireMagicLabel.getX();
                    int y = Frame.fireMagicLabel.getY();
                    Frame.fireMagicLabel.setLocation(x - 1, y);
                    LiveUpdating.updateSpell();
                    CheckHits.spellHit();
                    Frame.frame.repaint();

                    if (Frame.fireMagicLabel.getX() <= tempWest) {
                        timerWest.stop();
                        new Magic("");
                        Frame.frame.repaint();
                        Frame.fireMagicLabel.setLocation(
                                Frame.redHealthLabel.getX(),
                                Frame.redHealthLabel.getX());
                        isCasting = false;
                    }
                }
            });
            Frame.frame.repaint();

        }
```

On first run, the timer performs x speed.  Then the the next run it performs faster, and faster, and faster.

Comment: i think you should add the action listener only once.

Comment: @happymeal: make that an answer please!

Comment: Also as an aside, don't use `==` to compare Strings but rather use the `equals(...)` method.

Comment: @happymeal I think you're right.  I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

i think you should add the action listener only once.

Comment: I tried this but I couldn't figure out how to add the action listener once, but call it multiple times.

Comment: Trying to remove after code is executed: timerWest.removeActionListener(this);

Comment: Fixed it! Didn't exactly call it once, but removing it worked :)

Comment: you could add the listener in your constructor or have an initialing method which you only call once.

Comment: Actually it somewhat worked, whilst causing other bugs related.  I'll try only adding the listener once.

Answer (score 0):

Ther actionlistener is only needed to be added once.

Also if this does not fix it, somewhere inside the code you haven't posted you apply the speed, this might not be reset and be added on it, which makes it double speed.

Comment: How do I add the listener to the timer, without adding the actionperformed?  Can you show me an example?